# Modal don't appear in VueJs Components

Tags: modal-dialog

i've a problem,

My modal don't appear when the trigger of the modal under condition:

```
<div v-if="complete">
<a
    href="#small-dialog"
    class="popup-with-zoom-anim button full-width button-sliding-icon">
    Add Note
</a></div>
```

But when i remove `v-if="complete"` appear successfully.

Thank you.

Comment: have you checked `complete` value? you need to show more code than that. how is `complete` getting value ?

Comment: Yes i've cheched it, it return true when axios finished, also i'm using Vue chrome extension i can see the value of complete change from false to true, the trigger is there but the modal don't appear.

Comment: Can you add more code ? I don't see any modal in code. Without that it is impossible to figure out the issue.